# convert string to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I'd like to convert this string into a datetime object:

```
Wed Oct 20 16:35:44 +0000 2010
```

Is there a simple way to do this?  Or do I have to write a RE to parse the elements, convert Oct to 10 and so forth?

EDIT:
strptime is great.  However, with

```
datetime.strptime(date_str, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

I get

```
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y'
```

even though %z seems to be correct.

EDIT2:
The %z tag appears to not be supported.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue6641.
I got around it by using a timedelta object to modify the time appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where that string originates, you may be able to use [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to parse it. The only problem is that strptime relies on some platform-specific things, so if that string needs to be able to come from arbitrary other systems, and all the days and months aren't defined exactly the same (Jun or June), you may have troubles.

Answer (score 28):

No RE needed. Try this:

```
from dateutil import parser

yourDate = parser.parse(yourString)
```

for "Wed Oct 20 16:35:44 +0000 2010" returns `datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 20, 16, 35, 44, tzinfo=tzutc())`

Comment: dateutil is not in the standard library. It is is PyPI though, so `pip install python-dateutil' works. License is PSF.

Comment: Excellent! apt-get install python-dateutil

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're able to do that using datetime.strptime.

From the docs:

> datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
>
> Return a datetime corresponding to
> date_string, parsed according to
> format. This is equivalent to
> datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string,
> format)[0:6])). ValueError is raised
> if the date_string and format can’t be
> parsed by time.strptime() or if it
> returns a value which isn’t a time
> tuple.

Answer (score 1):

time.strptime should do it:
http://docs.python.org/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.strptime