# strptime - Python converting time to epoch time?

Tags: python, datetime, epoch

I am trying to convert time into epoch time. I am getting the error of: 
`ValueError: time data '11/Jan/2014:08:33:48 -0800' does not match format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z'`

```
import time

def epoch_time(epoch):
    d = "11/Jan/2014:08:33:48 -0800"
    p='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z'

    epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d,p)))
    print epoch
```

What is wrong with my above code?

My second question is where is TZ defined in os.environ[TZ]='UTC'? I found this in another post.

Update:
My data comes in this format:  11/Jan/2014:08:33:48 -0800 - it comes with time zone info of -8000. I can not modify the data but need to modify the code. Using Python 2.7.6

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> dd = parser.parse('11/Jan/2014:08:33:48 -0800')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 1008, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 395, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")
ValueError: Unknown string format
>>>
```

Comment: What's the exact version of your Python?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood `%Z`(Time zone name (no characters if no time zone exists).)

Try this:

```
import time

def epoch_time(epoch):
    d = "14/Jan/2014:09:36:50 PST"
    p='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z'

    epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(d,p)))
    print epoch
a = None
epoch_time(a)
```

[Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4018751/1099230), there is a better solution to your question.

```
from dateutil import parser
yourDate = parser.parse(yourString)
```

---

If you are using `python3`, as @jpmc26 recommended, use the `%z` syntax would be fine.

```
d = "11/Jan/2014:08:33:48 -0800"
p='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z' #python3 required
```

Comment: Actually my actual time is in this format: 11/Jan/2014:08:33:48 -0800 - it comes with time zone info of -8000. I can not modify the data but need to modify the code

Comment: @user4687194 Use lowercase `%z`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior. (Feel free to edit that into the answer if you like.)

Comment: When I use lowercase z, I get the error: ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'

Comment: Yes, `%z` was supported in `python3` add this to the answer. Meanwhile find a better solution. @user4687194.

Comment: Could you give a cleaner answer - I am getting errors. (I installed default util, no prob there)

Comment: @user4687194 I think the suggestion to use `dateutils` is as clean as you're going to get without upgrading or writing your own code.

Comment: Pls see my updated post - error "Unknown string format" - I get this error even without -8000, the timezone

Comment: How about `python3` and `%z`?

Comment: @jpmc26 what code upgrade is needed within this epoch conversion?